# Web services post request playframework 2.0.4

Tags: web-services, playframework-2.0, http-post

I'm trying to do a simple POST request to a google API from Play 2.0.4 using HTTPS
but I don't know how to post parameters.
I am using Java.

```
WS.url("https://myurl"). ... .post("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I think .setQueryParemeter is only for GET request.

Any help is welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

After looking around I found it.

```
WS.url("URL").post("param1=val1&param2=val2...");
```